# Rails validation uniqueness using scope with 2 different table columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've tables - rooms (id, room_number), facility_rooms (id, facility_id, room_id - reference column)

I want to ensure room_number should be unique per facility. So how can we write the rails validation with scope to refers the columns from 2 different tables? In this, I want the uniqueness in combination of room_number from rooms table and facility_id from facility_rooms table.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the validation in your model like below:

```
# facility_room.rb
class FacilityRoom
  validates :facility_id, uniqueness: { scope: :room_id, message: 'add validation error message here.' }
end
```

You can also add a unique index at the database level to avoid duplication in case the model validation is not able to catch the duplicates while processing concurrent requests:

```
class AddUniqueIndexToFacilityRooms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :facility_rooms, [:facility_id, :room_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Edited. You need to use the columns and not the assocation names for this to work. `validates_uniqueness_of` is a very leaky abstaction around a simple `WHERE EXISTS column_name = ?` query and it doesn't know that `facility` corresponds to `facility_id` column.